# Searching for a string in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

```
System.out.println("What animal are you looking for?");
String find=input.nextLine();
for(int i=0; i<array.size(); i++)
{
    if(array.get(i).equals(find))
    {
        System.out.println(array.get(i)+" is in the ArrayList"); 
    }
}
```

It returns nothing. What do you think is wrong with the code ? 
(It's supposed to take a string from from the user and try to find it in the ArrayList.)

Comment: What's the content of the list?

Comment: What about [`List.contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains(java.lang.Object))? What's your `array`?

Comment: Please post the complete code. It would help us!

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code?

Comment: do it with else condition inside for() and i think your arra doesn't contain the string..

Comment: @LuísSoares, it doesn't return `\n`, it returns the line without the line-breaking characters

Comment: Here is the rest of my code:

Comment: Can you show us an example? Which animals are in the list and which animal are you looking for? Keep in mind that this search (or Strings in general) is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible reasons for the `println` statement being skipped:

- The `ArrayList` is empty
- The `ArrayList` is not empty, but doesn't contain the searched word.

Just try debugging your code and you will find the reason very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Try without loop

```
if (array.contains(find)) {
    System.out.println(find + " is in the ArrayList"); 
}
```

But your code looks ok so it's most probable that you screw up something in code that you don't share here.

Comment: I think he mean "put this inside the for loop"

Answer (score 0):

This may help you :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ABC {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> Animals = new ArrayList<String>();
    Animals.add("Tiger");
    Animals.add("Lion");
    String input = null;
    System.out.println("Enter the name of the animal : ");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);  //Getting the name from the user
    input = in.nextLine();
    if (Animals.contains(input)) {        //Checking for presence 
        System.out.println("Present");
    }else
        System.out.println("Absent");
    }
}
```